# Where synaptic touchpad settings in user account?

Tags: touchpad

I have some trouble with my "synaptics touchpad"

The touchpad is one of those that use the `psmouse` kernel module (i.e. `modprobe psmouse` will get the pad to work [mouse moves] and `modprobe -r psmouse` unloads it and the mouse does not work anymore).

My problem is that in one (my main) user account the touchpad stopped working. But only in that user account, it is still working on the login screen and in other user accounts.

My question is where could be the user-account specific settings linked to the touchpad. It seems to me that there must be some settings that are linked to my account that cause the touchpad not to work anymore.

It is still shown in the output of `xinput`

```
user@box:~# xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

output from `xinput list`

```
user@mybox$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I can get the mouse to work using this commands

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

The whole problem seems very odd to me since I thought the settings to mouse and X-server are more made "outside the user account settings".

I am happy for a hint where to find the "account specific touchpad settings"

I use 12.04 Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Well I haven't found the config file for the touchpad, but I did found this:

`Touchpad-Indicator`

With this simple tool you can disable your touchpad with key-shortcuts etc.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Install Touchpad-Indicator:

Open a Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type in the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

### Alternative to Touchpad-Indicator --> gpointing-device-settings:

1. open a Terminal. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Type in: `sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings`
3. After the installation is complete type in `gpointing-device-settings` and press enter. It will automatically open a window with the `Touchpad-Setting` as well as the `Mouse-Setting` (only if you have a mouse plugged in).

### If that does not solve your problem then try this:

1. open a Terminal. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Type in: `xinput list`

**NOTE: If one of the lines mentions a touchpad or glidepoint (perhaps also "Synaptics" or "ALPS"), your touchpad has been detected.



If one of the lines mentions an "ADB mouse", then your touchpad is old. Use the trackpad command line tool to configure it. Here's an example to switch on tapping and dragging:**

```
sudo trackpad show
sudo trackpad tap
sudo trackpad drag
```

And if none of the above work check here: [SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I like that suggestion with the `Touchpad-Indicator` but I cannot find it in synaptics/apt-get install nor do I have it as a command being able to be run at command line. How to run it? Thank you!

Comment: `xinput list` (in my setup) renders the same result as `xinput` without parameters. I have stated in my question the result. It seems I have xinput "**see**" my touchpad, though it seems not working.

Comment: right yeah sorry... I edited my answer.

Comment: Oh and I found the config file you were looking for: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

Comment: Thank you @MrSeed. The trouble with that config file is that it is "global" (shared between the user accounts) and hence I doubt can be the culprit/cause because then the touchpad would not be working in all user accounts. But it is only malfuncitoning in one user account. It is indeed strange. Thank you for your effort