# Local settings interfere with trackpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, mate

Using Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, MATE desktop.

I had an older Lenovo laptop with a trackpad, which I used for ~ 5 years. After some amount of time, the trackpad stopped working, I assumed because of a hardware issue, so I used an external mouse instead.

Now, I bought a new laptop which also has a trackpad. It works fine with the initial account I created. Then I copied my entire home directory from the old machine to the new machine. After I did that, after logging into the new account, the trackpad stops working again.

I still have the alternate user account, and when I log in that one, the trackpad works again. It only stops working when I log into the account with the migrated home directory.

In both accounts I can see the touchpad under `xinput list`.

---

It seems like I should be able to find out what bad configuration in my home directory is messing with the trackpad, however, when I perform internet searches to find what files may be relevant, I usually get references to paths like

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/etc/...
```

which are not in the home directory.

In my home directory, I see

```
~/.config/ubuntu-mate
~/.config/mate
~/.config/mate-session
~/.config/dconf
```

I don't see anything in these files that seems relevant to trackpads.

I found this question from 10 years ago where similarly, no one seemed to be able to identify settings files relevant to trackpads.

[Where synaptic touchpad settings in user account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296563/where-synaptic-touchpad-settings-in-user-account)

Is it still the case that there no known specific settings files relevant to trackpads in the home directory?

I suppose I can start doing things like deleting `.config` and seeing if that fixes it, and then trying to iterate that way to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my trackpad by deleting `.config/dconf/user`

(actually I just renamed it to `user.old`).

However, it messes up some other desktop settings I had.

I suppose I will try to find a tool to read dconf files and figure out what bad trackpad setting there was in there, since it is binary format.

---

I was able to figure out the problem using `gsettings` which I had to `apt install`.

Using `gsettings list-schemas` I saw three schemas which seemed like they could be relevant.

I used gsettings to dump these schemas:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
gsettings list-recursively org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.mouse
gsettings list-recursively org.mate.peripherals-touchpad
```

Under `org.mate.peripherals-touchpad` I had:

```
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad accel-profile 'default'
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad disable-while-typing true
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad horizontal-edge-scrolling false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad horizontal-two-finger-scrolling false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad motion-acceleration -1.0
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad motion-threshold -1
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad natural-scroll false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-one-finger 1
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-three-finger 2
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-two-finger 3
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-to-click true
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad three-finger-click 0
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad touchpad-enabled false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad two-finger-click 0
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-edge-scrolling true
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-two-finger-scrolling true
```

This command fixed it:

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

Once I ran that my touchpad worked again

Hope this helps someone in the future